# How to use NestWhile to get it to work the way I want?

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I have a vector th={0,0,...,1.57}. Now I want to choose the second element and change it by stepsize 0.2 until it is less than 1.57, I need these set of vectors:
th={0,0.2,0,...,1.57}

th={0,0.4,0,...,1.57}

th={0,0.6,0,...,1.57}

th={0,0.8,...,1.57}

th={0,1,0,...,1.57}

th={0,1.2,0,...,1.57}

th={0,1.4,0,...,1.57}

while the second element is 0.2 for example, I need to change the third the element with the same step-size and  repeat the same procedure while the second element is 0.4,0.6 ,...,1.4

th={0,0.2,0.2,0,0,0...,1.57},{0,0.2,0.4,0...,1.57},{0,0.2,0.6,0...,1.57},{0,0.2,0.8,0...,1.57},,{0,0.2,1,0...,1.57},{0,0.2,1.2,0...,1.57},th={0,0.2,1.4,0...,1.57}

th={0,0.4,0.2,0,...,1.57},{0,0.4,0.4,0...,1.57},{0,0.4,0.6,0...,1.57},{0,0.4,0.8,0...,1.57},{0,0.4,1,0...,1.57},{0,0.4,1.2,0...,1.57},th={0,0.4,1.4,0...,1.57}

th={0,0.6,0.2,0,...,1.57},...

.
.
.

th={0,1.4,.2,0,...,1.57},{0,1.4,0.4,0...,1.57},{0,1.4,0.6,0...,1.57},{0,1.4,0.8,0...,1.57},{0,1.4,1,0...,1.57},{0,1.4,1.2,0...,1.57},th={0,1.4,1.4,0...,1.57}

until I cover all the possible angle sets.

I have written this code which does not do what I want at all, I want to have all the possible angle sets, Could somebody please help me to fix this code so I can get it to do what I want?

```
 th = Table[0, {k, 1, ne}];
 th[[ne]] = \[Pi]/2 // N;
 j = 0.2;
 Table[
 NestWhile[th
 , (th[[i]] = th[[i]] + j;
  th) , (th[[i]] + j) < 1.57], {i, 2, ne - 1}]
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you clarify what the dots mean in "..."?

Comment: Does something like `Tuples[Range[0, 1.57, 0.2], 4]` get you most of the way (for the exemplary case of 4 looping indices)? It returns a list of all such lists, not including the first (zero) and last (1.57) elements. You can add those with `{0, ##, 1.57} & @@@ Tuples[Range[0, 1.57, 0.2], 4]`

Comment: @A.G. By dots I mean do the same procedure as before, I will try to Edit my explanation

Comment: @A.G. I wrote the values to be more clear. the dots inside the brackets means zeros.